# Modulo operator usage while dealing with doubles

Tags: c++, c, modulo

I have to find the value of ( 1+sqrt(3) )^n where n < 10^9.As this number can be very large we have to print the ans%1000000007.
I have written the following function for this.

```
double power(double x, int y)
{
    double temp;
    if( y == 0)
       return 1;
    temp = power(x, y/2);
    if (y%2 == 0)
       return temp*temp;
    else
    {
       if(y > 0)
           return x*temp*temp;
       else
           return (temp*temp)/x;
    }
}
```

Now, I unable to understand how to take care of the modulo condition.Can somebody please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. You could use `fmod`, but since `sqrt(3)` cannot be exactly represented, you'd get bogus values for large exponents.

I'm rather confident that you actually need integer results (`(1 + sqrt(3))^n + (1 - sqrt(3))^n`), so you should use integer math, exponentiation by squaring with a modulo operation at each step. cf. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301992/i-want-to-generate-the-nth-term-of-the-sequence-1-3-8-22-60-164-in-order1-or)

Answer (score 0):

This approach is infeasible. As shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356141/calculating-large-powers-of-a-double-with-modulus-1000-000-007), you would need hundreds of millions of decimal digits more precision than the double type supplies. The problem you are actually trying to solve is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301992/i-want-to-generate-the-nth-term-of-the-sequence-1-3-8-22-60-164-in-order1-or). Are you two in the same class?

Answer (score 0):

modulo needs integer type, you could use union for your double type unioned with an integer to use the modulo(if this is C)